# Casting floats and UILabel

Tags: iphone, ios, casting, uilabel, nsnumber

HI -

I have a value in a UILabel and I want to pass the number to a value that is of float type.

```
rate = float
hourlyRate = label
```

Below is my code and im getting errors.  I know its bad form to go from object to primitive values but there has to be a way.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
rate = NSNumber numberWithFloat:[hourlyRate.text rate];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSString has a convenient floatValue method:

```
rate = [hourlyRate.text floatValue];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rate = NSNumber numberWithFloat:[hourlyRate.text rate];
```

That’s invalid because if you’re trying to send the message `numberWithFloat:` to NSNumber it has to be enclosed in brackets, like so:

```
rate = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[hourlyRate.text rate]];
```

And what’s more `hourlyRate.text` returns an NSString. You can’t send an NSString the method `rate` unless you subclassed it and added that method.

This is the right way to get the float value of UILabel, try this:

```
rate = [hourlyRate.text floatValue];
```

And do you mean:

```
float rate;
```